# Generic type definition in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

I have 2 api calls which returns me data in below format in my angular project.

- In 1st api, I get `response` in below generic as array as per `IMap`
- In 2nd ap, I get `response` in below generic as object as per
  `IBenefit`

My Generic interface is:

```
export interface Generic<T> {
    responseCode: string;
    message: string;
    response: T[];
}
```

`IMap` interface is below:

```
export interface IMap {
    countryCode: string;
    countryName: string;
    numberOfAccounts: number;
    totalAmount: number;
    surplusAmount: number;
    deficitAmount: number;
    offsetAmount: number;
    noOfCurrencies: number;
    accounts: [
        {
            accountId: string;
            accountName: string;
            accountLocationCode: string;
            accountCity: string;
            accountHoldingEntity: string;
            accountHoldingEntityLocationCode: string;
            accountDescription: string;
            accountCurrencyCode: string;
            balanceCurrencyCode: string;
            averageBalance: number
        }
    ];
}
```

`Ibenefit` interface is below.

```
export interface IBenefit {
    marketBenefits: object;
    currencyBenefits: object;
    totalBenefits: object;
    yield: object;
}
```

This works for first API which is obvious with `response:T[]` param having `IMap[]` but fails for `IBenfit` as its not array.

How to write generic so that passed type `T` can represent both `Array` and `Object`.

basically It should work for both `Generic<IMap>` and `Generic<IBenefit>` where `response:T` can be array or object

Comment: Why don't you wrap the second response in array from the backend?

Comment: Another possibility could be declare the response as T and when construct the Generic have parameterized type as array or object. Not fully sure though it will accept array as type T.

Comment: @fiveelements that would be unnecessary alteration to the response that we would tend to avoid

Comment: What about the second approach? You can make it `response: T` instead of `response: T[]` in Generic type. That way you can both array and object to it.

Comment: In that case `IMap` would fail as api returning me array of object of type `IMap`

Comment: Then jus simply write `Generic<IMap[]>` the answer from @fiveelements is the right one

Comment: instead of you can use this one Union types  ```export interface Generic<T> {
    responseCode: string;
    message: string;
    response: T[] | T;
}
```
This will adjust automatically.
```
export interface Generic<T> {
    responseCode: string;
    message: string;
    response: T;
}
```

Comment: Yes, union type is another way if do not wish to change how Generic<T> is constructed.

Comment: ok..when using union it throws error `marketBenefits doesn't exist on type IBenefit | IBenefit[]`.

I used it in this way `Generic<IBenefit>`